# PowerShell script failing after build completed on TFS 2010 build server

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm using TFS 2010 as a build server and I have modified the build template to invoke a powershell script if the build compiles, using an invoke process item.

The problem I have is that while the script runs fine if I run it manually (with elevated permissions it has to be said) on the TFS server (logged in with the same account used to run the build service) it does not run fully.

the script below, which I used for testing, outputs all the "echoes" but it does not create a file. I've checked the permissions on the directory and the user had full control.

There are no errors on the event log or indeed TFS.

Any ideas?

TIA

```
echo "Start script"

echo "Get Date"

$filename = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")+ ".txt"

echo "Write Date to file"

(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm") >> $filename

echo "Finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the file first and then writing to it? Or just a different way of creating/writing to the file?

[New-Item (create new file) on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx)

[Out-File (write to a file)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx)

```
$filename = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")+ ".txt"
echo $filename

$filepath = "C:\" + $filename
New-Item $filepath -type file

if (Test-Path $filepath)
{ echo "file exists!"}
else { echo "file doesn't exist"}

(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm") | Out-File $filepath
```

Comment: What do you mean "close"? Was the file created? Did the echos work? Does your build service account have permissions to create files? Are you looking in the right places for the files?

Comment: the echoes work, they always have.
the build service account has full control on the directory